# How to change a game from Simultaneous Turns to Dynamic Turns and hotseat/multiplayer/singleplayer?

Tags: civilization-6

Once a game has been started, how do you change it from Simultaneous Turns to Dynamic Turns or Vice Versa?

Also, is it possible to change from Hotseat to regular multiplayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally these settings cannot be changed once a game is started however if you go to %UserProfile%\Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization VI\Saves\ here you can find Single, Multi, and Hotseat folders.

Select the save game you want to edit and replace with the following:

```
**hex values**  = **function**       = **notepad++**
00 4d b6 b3 9a  = dynamic turns      = M¶³š
00 bf b6 ab 9a  = simultaneous turns = ¿¶«š
```

For example if you want to make a simultaneous turn game dynamic you can find and replace `¿¶«š` with `M¶³š` or you can use the hex address with a hex editor this process can also be reversed. As an added bonus you can move saves between the Single Multi and Hotseat folders to "convert" them to the respective modes. **It should be noted using regular notepad causes the save to crash your game so only use notepad++.**

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried changing from dynamic to simultaneous, and the game was still dynamic turns.

Comment: @whoKnows can you provide the before and after save

Comment: I've just tried and it does WORK! Thanks for the solution, @CodeCamper!

Comment: @AdiFurca Glad to hear it is working for you!