# How can we setup a cloud-based multiplayer game with simultaneous turns in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

We want to play a Civ 6 Cloud Multiplayer game with simultaneous rounds. The game will run parallel to our daily lives and everyone will try to do one round a day. If we were to play in dynamic turns, it would mean that a turn would last almost a week (we don't sit non-stop in front of a computer and when it's someone's turn it takes at least 1 day to make a move). But if we make our turn simultaneously, the same would last about a day. (It is also important that all human players will be on the same team, so war against each other in simultaneous play is not a problem (playing against each other when rounds are not in order, sometimes a player can hit twice in a row if he is the last to finish a round and immediately start the next one).

So my problem is how to set up the game for simultaneous multiplayer in the cloud!

Here is a link to do so, but it doesn't work:

[Civilzation 6 how to change a game from Simultaneous Turns to Dynamic Turns and hotseat/multiplayer/singleplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347352/civilzation-6-how-to-change-a-game-from-simultaneous-turns-to-dynamic-turns-and)